# SOLR Master-Slave Repeater with Load balancer

Tags: solr, load, repeater, master-slave

We are trying to setup solr Master Slave repeater model, where we will have two solr servers say S1 and S2 and a Load balancer LB to route all the requests to either S1 or S2. S1 and S2 acts as both Master and Slave(Repeater). In both the solr server configurations, in the solrconfig.xml file for master url property if we provide Load balancer host-name and port number then at any point there will be a self polling, i.e. if LB is configured in such a way that all its requests will be routed to S1, then while polling S1-->LB-->S1 and S2-->LB-->S1. Do you see any issue with self polling(S1-->LB-->). We are mainly trying to achieve High availability as we don't want to use Solr Cloud.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you wouldn't want to use SolrCloud?

Comment: Solr Cloud requires atleast 3 servers and recommended is 5 servers (as per zoo keeper doc), due to budget limitation we can have only 2 servers. Moreover Solr cloud is more beneficial if we really do data sharding, which we will not be implementing as our data size is small.